# dracut-pre-trigger rd.md=0 removing md raid activation boot fails

Tags: raid, boot, mdadm, md, dracut

The system is Fedora 22, recently upgraded from Fedora 21. The remaining kernel from Fedora 21 boots. The two kernels installed after the upgrade fail to boot.

The system is an Intel S-5000 PAL with 5 SATA drives configured in raid 5 array. It has been running without issue for nearly 2 years. And as mentioned above continues to run with out issue with the Fedora 21 kernel.

The issue is with upgraded kernels the boot process hangs and after 3 minutes drops into the emergency shell. The journelctl output shows the following error messages:

> systemctl: Starting dracut pre-trigger hook..
>
> lldpad: config file file failed to load,
>
> lldpad: create a new file
>
> lldpad: bound ctrl iface to /com/intel/lldpad
>
> dracut-pre-trigger: dracut-pre-trigger: rd.md=0 removing md raid
> activation

At the end of the process the error message is:

> raidboot /root device not found

The Fedora 21 kernels boot and runs normally. The following has been tried:

1. rebuild initramfs
2. run grub2-mkconfig and reinstall grub

As further background this server is part of a network of similar servers. The upgrade of the other servers was successful. A comparison of the lsinit output for the two initramfs.img files shows similar output. The only differences are in the area of pre-trigger and lldpad.

Is Pre-Trigger configuration the cause of this?
What step is missing to cause dracut-pre-trigger fail in creating initramfs?
What packages are required to support pre-trigger?
What configuration is involved in pre-trigger?
pre-trigger be re-run to support creating initramfs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ended up on being a long trail with a simple answer. The systems use mdadm to create a level 5 raid pv. Dracut was updated as part of the upgrade from fc21 to fc22 along with the kernel. The intitial boot command line in grub.cfg had a rd.lvm.lv option. This caused the fc22 dracut stop looking for dm arrays early in the boot process. Removing the rd.lvm.lv option from the vmlinuz command options in grub.cfg along with adding a rd.auto option fixed the problem. 
The key was reading the Dracut documentation which referred to the rd.lvm.lv option as being exclusive. The exclusive option may have been phased in resulting a delay in imposing the restriction.